# Django 1.10: login required middleware redirect loop

Tags: django, python-2.7, authentication, django-middleware

I'm writing a bit of middleware to effectively make `@login_required` on all pages.  Unfortunately what I've got results in a redirect loop.

The implementation is using "old" style middleware with 1.10 via `MiddlewareMixin` and `process_request()` hook in attempt to redirect to login page whenever the user is not authenticated.

First, I'm using the default auth urls `django.contrib.auth.urls`. The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) say:

> This will include the following URL patterns: `^login/$ [name='login']`...

```
# main URLConf urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views
]
```

Then here's the middleware (yes it's added to `MIDDLEWARE` in `settings.py`):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class LoginRequiredMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

The login page/functionality works fine when the my middleware isn't included, while including it results in every url causing `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doh! I needed to check for `/login/` in `process_request` and ignore it.

Here's a simplified version of what is implemented. The real version uses  `settings.py` and regexes to define the login exempt urls.  Much credit to Ryan Witt's [post](http://onecreativeblog.com/post/59051248/django-login-required-middleware) on this approach.

```
class LoginRequiredMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')
            # If path is not root url ('') and path is not exempt from authentication
            if not path or not any(path != eu for eu in ["/login", "admin"]):
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/login/")
```

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi I got it.  I'll add some detail to my answer in a few moments. Thanks.